# "Looks like" in more formal way

Tags: word-usage, formality, phrase-usage

I want to write

> It looks like I misunderstood Berta's explanation

But in more formal way.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally "It appears" or "It would appear that" are somewhat closer to what you seem to be looking for, though it's not really *formal* language, per se.

Comment: "Upon closer examination, it appears that..."

Answer (score 3):

The preposition *like* is generally considered a bit informal when followed by a clause:

- It looks like [I misunderstood Berta's explanation]

But is slightly less informal when followed by a noun phrase:

- It looks like [rain].

If you want to achieve a less informal effect you can use a preposition phrase headed by *as though*:

> It looks as though I misunderstood Berta's explanation.

Notice that you can't use this with a noun phrase:

> *It looks as though rain

**Grammar Note**

In traditional grammar prepositions such as *like* and *as though* are termed subordinating conjunctions when followed by a clause. Some modern grammars, such as *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts, call them *conjunctive prepositions*. A nice fix perhaps.

Comment: For once, I've upvoted an answer to what I think a question unsuitable for ELU. How do you find OMEG (good job it's Oxford not Stanford)? I've always been impressed by Aarts' analyses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I find it very clear and precise and useful! But I should point out that I was a student of Bas', so I might be a bit biased. One thing I would say is that, probably because Bas worked with Quirk, Greenbaum Leech and Svartvik, and because he's not entrenched in any particular paradigm of linguistics, his analysis manages to be modern and clear, but at the same time readable and accessible to traditional grammarians. He also includes further literature and mkes it clear when there are competing analyses with the one he's presenting ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ... Obviously, it's a much more modest work than say the Comprehensive Grammar or the Cambridge Grammar (the two mighty CGEL's), but it's clear modern, descriptive as well as theoretical and like Quirk et al, but unlike H&P, all the examples are authentic, most taken from the ICE-GB corpus, and a few others from published medai. It's got a lot going for it, imo.

Comment: Thank you. '[He makes] it clear when there are competing analyses with the one he's presenting' is a top recommendation IMHO. Some grammars sound like they assume an inerrancy-and-infallibility stance.